# How to I sort a pandas dataframe by values while preserving duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate total pay of NYC employees from this database. https://www.kaggle.com/new-york-city/nyc-citywide-payroll-data/version/1

First I converted floats to integers

```
df['Base_Salary'] = df['Base Salary'].astype(int)
df['Total_OT_Paid'] = df['Total OT Paid'].astype(int)
df['Regular_Hours'] = df['Regular Hours'].astype(int)
df['OT_Hours'] = df['OT Hours'].astype(int)
df['Regular_Gross_Paid'] = df['Regular Gross Paid'].astype(int)
```

Then created a new column
`df.assign(Total_Pay = df.Regular_Gross_Paid + df.Total_OT_Paid)`

But now when I try this code to sort by Total Pay using this line of code
`df.sort_values(by=[Total_Pay], inplace=True)`

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-4900b8a054f9> in <module>
----> 1 df.sort_values([Total_Pay], axis=1, inplace=True)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in sort_values(self, by, axis, ascending, inplace, kind, na_position, ignore_index)
   4925 
   4926             by = by[0]
-> 4927             k = self._get_label_or_level_values(by, axis=axis)
   4928 
   4929             if isinstance(ascending, (tuple, list)):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1690             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1691         else:
-> 1692             raise KeyError(key)
   1693 
   1694         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: [47223, 119042, 27473, 115104, 3500, 71967, 87614, 500, 9507, 64357, 6073, 39895, 65909, 111806, 77833, 3500, 41465, 59023, 3500, 39866, 64498, 189618, 1000, 65593, 54028, 7425, 4830, 35765, 64895, 55411, 26437, 71525, 104059, 88581, 20058, 64375, 47113, 10265, 40173, 71668, 86719, 1000, 42673, 36699, 65833, 66293, 48775, 150567, 16960, 36148, 43651, 137294, 48328, 60869, 163658, 80304, 32249, 37859, 4879, 130607, 40604, 35220, 500, 16197, 35782, 49283, 173692, 47144, 85183, 51446, 185049, 22101, 152054, 60622, 42699, 46157, 45050, 77790, 21976, 51446, 3500, 2250, 3500, 182066, 3500, 1750, 48797, 71525, 192012, 718, 37117, 47527, 4734, 106820, 127128, 152308, 41546, 1000, 47112, 33033, 141960, 55724, 28421, 22388, 80247, 83066, 48818, 9529, 80764, 44705, 64168, 46562, 80124, 73949, 3500, 33585, 2250, 125051, 64364, 65236, 35066, 24196, 48775, 4968, 39687, 55249, 74878, 80204
```

That list of keyerrors goes on for a long time...

Comment: hm trying to run that gets me "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"

Comment: `df.assign` returns a new DataFrame with the new columns in addition to all the existing columns. Are you reassigning the output of `df.assign` to the desired frame? `df = df.assign(Total_pay ...)`